# timeseries forecasting using Neural Network

Tags: neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am stuck with a timeseries forecasting problem to forecast end of day balance. I have 2 years of data with daily closing balance for some 100 accounts. Trying to create forecast to predict future values using MLP and LSTM's but both are giving non satisfactory results. Both the model capture the linear trend in the data correctly but fail to recognize any non linear changes.

Here is my approach:

Feature Engg performed:

1. Took last 5 lag values for each day as input
2. Day, Month and Weekday extrapolated and fed as input

So, I have 8 columns as input to the model and data is scaled using MinMaxScaler before passing to model.

LSTM Model:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(32,return_sequences = True, input_shape=(1, 8)))
    model.add(LSTM(32))
    model.add(Dense(1 , activation='linear'))
    model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
```

MLP Model:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu', input_dim=trainX.shape[1]))
    model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
    model.fit(trainX,trainY, epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=0, 
    shuffle=False)
```

Am I doing anything wrong and how can this model be improved to better perform on non linear values? Here is a sample of actual values vs prediction that I am getting.

```
                 predicted       actual     Mape %
    date            
    2017-11-01   3.427375e+07   75248606.05  74.82
    2017-11-02   3.516451e+07   65382560.38  60.11
    2017-11-03   3.592537e+07   64244508.86 56.54
    2017-11-04   3.796975e+07   64244508.86 51.41
    2017-11-05   3.806401e+07   64244508.86 51.18
    2017-11-06   3.994756e+07   60844214.61 41.47
    2017-11-07   4.147836e+07   57346364.66 32.11
    2017-11-08   4.280740e+07   48821953.03 13.13
    2017-11-09   4.481559e+07   49061219.17 9.05
    2017-11-10   4.662069e+07   45530356.65 2.37
```

Comment: If using LSTM try big hidden_units  e.g. 200,300.

And for your problem, I think the balance is more monthly or bi-weekly updated, so tracking day balance may can't get good result.